# Vert.x: Deploying a JavaScript Verticle from Java fails

Tags: javascript, java, maven, vert.x

I want to deploy a JavaScipt-written Verticle with Java. But I always get a `ClassNotFoundErrorException` - although the Path is correct and the `vertx-lang-js` resource is added.

This is my JS-Verticle:

```
declare var vertx;    
var eb = new vertx.EventBus()
eb.consumer("cbweb.validation", (message:any) => {
    console.log(message);
});
console.log("Validation.js ready")
```

And here is my Java-Code for deploying the Verticle:

```
private static final String RELATIVE_PATH = "D:/Temp/vertxFtpClient/jslibs/jsftp/verticle.js";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(new BasicVerticle(), stringAsyncResult -> {
        System.out.println("BasicVerticle deployment complete");
    });


    vertx.deployVerticle(RELATIVE_PATH);

    vertx.close();

}
```

}

and here is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.vertex.ftp</groupId>
    <artifactId>VertexAdapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-lang-js</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>VertexLearning</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Maybe something is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use just JavaScript you don't need to write java code at all. All you need is to add your js code to `src/main/resources` (you could change this to something else but you will need to tweak maven not to use its defaults).

And the use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) as this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
              <Main-Verticle>${main.verticle}</Main-Verticle>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <artifactSet>
        </artifactSet>
        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And declare a variable `main.verticle` with your js verticle file path relative from `src/main/resource` e.g.: `jslibs/jsftp/verticle.js`.